# c++ code won't compile

Tags: c++, makefile, g++

Helo there,  i am trying to compile my c++ code in Ubuntu using g++.

I have 3 files: Ball.h Ball.cpp main.cpp

header file Ball.h

```
#ifdef BALL_H_
#define BALL_H_
class Ball {

public:
Ball();
Ball(int radius);
~Ball();

void setRadius(int);
int getRadius();

private:

int radius;


};

#endif //BALL_H_
```

Ball.cpp file

```
#include "Ball.h"

Ball::Ball() {

radius = 1;

}

Ball::Ball(int rad) {

radius = rad;

}

Ball::~Ball() {

}

void Ball::setRadius(int rad) {

radius = rad;

}

int Ball::getRadius() {

return radius;

}
```

main.cpp file

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Ball.h"


using namespace std;

int main() {

//Ball b, b2, b3(2);

Ball b = Ball();
Ball b2 = Ball();
Ball b3 = Ball(2);

cout << "Initial radius: ";
    <<b.getRadius() << endl;

b.setRadius(10);

cout << "New radius: "
    << b.getRadius() << endl;

cout << "Initial radius b2: "
    << b2.getRadius() << endl;

b2.setRadius(20);

cout << "b/b2"
    << b.getRadius() << "/"
    << b2.getRadius() << endl;


cout <<"b3 radius: "
    << b3.getRadius() << endl;  
return 0;

}
```

when i am trying to compile all these 3 files, compilator can't even find Ball objects that are declared in main.cpp  I am using makefile to compile these 3 files.

Makefile:

```
GPP=g++
GPPOPT=-std=c++11

OBJ=Ball main

all: $(OBJ)

Ball:
$(GPP) $(GPPOPT) -c Ball.cpp -o $@

main:
$(GPP) $(GPPOPT) main.cpp -o $@


 clean: 
-$(RM) $(OBJ)
```

Compilator message:

```
m4r1us@ubuntu:~/Desktop/cpptest$ make
g++ -std=c++11 -c Ball.cpp -o Ball
Ball.cpp:3:2: error: ‘Ball’ does not name a type
Ball::Ball() {
^
Ball.cpp:9:2: error: ‘Ball’ does not name a type
Ball::Ball(int rad) {
^
Ball.cpp:15:2: error: ‘Ball’ does not name a type
Ball::~Ball() {
^
Ball.cpp:19:7: error: ‘Ball’ has not been declared
void Ball::setRadius(int rad) {
     ^
Ball.cpp: In function ‘void setRadius(int)’:
Ball.cpp:21:2: error: ‘radius’ was not declared in this scope
radius = rad;
 ^
Ball.cpp: At global scope:
Ball.cpp:25:6: error: ‘Ball’ has not been declared
int Ball::getRadius() {
     ^
Ball.cpp: In function ‘int getRadius()’:
Ball.cpp:27:9: error: ‘radius’ was not declared in this scope
return radius;
        ^
make: *** [Ball] Error 1
m4r1us@ubuntu:~/Desktop/cpptest$
```

I think there are some problems with compiling. I can't figure what i am doing wrong. Any tips for me?

Thank You.

Comment: Typo: you need `#ifndef`, not `#ifdef` here: `#ifdef BALL_H_`.

Comment: unrelated: `Ball b = Ball();` should really be just `Ball b;`, as otherwise you are making an extra copy (this is not Java). Similarly, `Ball b2 = Ball(2)` should be just `Ball b2(2);`

Comment: The makefile is wrong too. You are generating an object file called `Ball`, and and an executable called `main` which does not link to `Ball`.  Instead you should generate object file `Ball.o` and link it into `main`.

Comment: *Try something simpler first.* You should never write this much code without testing any of it.

Answer (score 3):

Check your header guards. You have `#ifdef BALL_H_` when it should be `#ifndef BALL_H_`.

Comment: Thanks, another compilation error: main.cpp:(.text+0x13): undefined reference to `Ball::Ball()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x30): undefined reference to `Ball::Ball(int)'
etc..

Comment: You need to compile both files with the `-c` flag, then link them together properly. For example: `g++ -o program.out Ball.o main.o`. See if you can find a tutorial on compiling/linking using GCC.